# Can I run an android test case in an android application?

Tags: android, testing

I want to run an android test case which from an android test project in a android application,such as i click a button then a test case start, i do not konw how to do it.

Comment: Ummm... What? Your question is very unclear. Can you try editing it so we can tell what exactly you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start, it well described
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

See the test example for HelloWorld first. Follow the steps as i said it's well described.
Then create a test project for your app and If you get stuck somewhere try adjusting the code from the example for your app.

Comment: I already have a test project A to test android project B, but i want to creat a new android project C and in C i want to run test project A, is it possible?

Comment: So you want to test a TestProject from another TestProject? In Android you cannot create TestProject to test another TestProject. TestProjects are created for testing your application and nothing more.

Comment: no,C is a android Project,not a TestProject, i just want to call a test case in an Activity,is it possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible if you create TestProject for the Android project you want to test. If the answer helped you please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hackbod and his answer is perfect so I copy it here:
ere is already an API for this, Context.startInstrumentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startInstrumentation(android.content.ComponentName, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)